# Integrate Diffusion Equation: $\frac{dG(t)}{dt} = k(\frac{a}{b+G(t)} - \frac{c}{d-G(t)})$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function

**Background**

I am trying to determine the total diffusion of water across a cell membrane after some time $t$. The experiment is set up by placing potato cores in sucrose solutions of different concentrations and measuring weight change of the potato cores after a constant time. (I know this sounds like biology but this question is strictly mathematical).

**My Attempt**

Basically, from Fick's Second Law of Diffusion, we know that the rate of diffusion is proportional to the concentration gradient. In my case, this means:

$$J = k \Delta C$$

where $J$ is the rate of diffusion (I'll use L/s for simplicity), $k$ is a diffusion constant and $\Delta C$ is the concentration gradient ($C_{out}-C_{in}$ where $C$ is solute concentration in M).

I can rewrite the equation to be more explicit like so:

$$J = k(\frac{a}{b}-\frac{c}{d})$$

where $a$ and $c$ are moles of solute in the potato core and solution respectively and $b$ and $d$ are liters of water in each respectively. As the water diffuses, $a$ and $c$ remain constant.

Therefore, I can determine $J(t)$ as the following:

$$J(t) = k(\frac{a}{b+\int_{0}^{t}J dt} - \frac{c}{d - \int_{0}^{t}Jdt})$$

Or perhaps simpler, given $G(t) = \int_{0}^{t}Jdt$, (the total amount of water diffused by time $t$),

$$\frac{dG(t)}{dt} = k(\frac{a}{b+G(t)} - \frac{c}{d-G(t)})$$

(after time $t$, a certain amount of water $G(t)$ has crossed the membrane and increased the volume in the potato cores while decreasing the volume in the solution)

At this point I am stuck. I have not been able to figure out a general solution for this differential equation. I feel like this will end up being some exponential solution but it is beyond my capabilities to solve. Could someone with more advanced skills help me out?

**Goal**

I would like to obtain $G$, the total water diffused, as a function of $t$, the elapsed time, given $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, and $k$ as constants.

Comment: It's non-linear ODE so it is likely not going to have a "nice" solution.  You can always use numerical methods for particular initial conditions.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know whether your physics is right or not. Here I just talk abut the integration.

As you pointed that 
\begin{equation}
\frac{dG(t)}{dt} = k \left( \frac{a}{b+G} -\frac{c}{d-G}\right)
\end{equation}

Then you can rewrite it into 
\begin{equation}
\frac{dG(t)}{dt} = k\left( \frac{(a-c)G+ad-bc}{(b+G)(d-G)} \right)
\end{equation}
This leads to 
\begin{equation}
\int \frac{(b+G)(d-G)}{(a-c)G+ad-bc}dG = \int kdt
\end{equation}
This further leads to 
\begin{equation}
-\frac{1}{a-c}\int \left(G+\frac{ad-bc}{a-c} + \frac{\frac{(a-c)(b-d)-2(ab-bc)}{a-c}G-\left(\frac{ad-bc}{a-c} \right)^2-bd}{G+\frac{ad-bc}{a-c}}\right)dG = \int kdt
\end{equation}

The second integration term could be written to more general form as $\frac{k_1G+k_2}{k_3G+k_4}$.  Now considering a general form integration of function $\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$ whose integration result is as 
\begin{equation}
\int \frac{ax+b}{cx+d} dx = a\left( \frac{x}{c}-\frac{d}{c^2}\ln(cx+d)\right) + b\ln(cx+d)
\end{equation}

So using this general integration result you would be able to get the integration with respect to G

Comment: Thanks so much, this looks really promising. I'm relatively new to calculus and still learning, could you explain how you got from your first integral to the second one? I can't quite see the steps you took. (going from where you said 'this leads to' to 'this further leads to')

Comment: Check the added answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a bit of linear algebra. The process looks like this

\begin{equation}
   \frac{ (b+G)(d-G)}{(a-c)G+ad-bc}
\end{equation}
It could be rewritten as 
\begin{equation}
    \frac{-1}{a-c} \frac{(G+b)(G-d)}{G-\frac{ad-bc}{a-c}}
\end{equation}
Further goes to 
\begin{equation}
    \frac{-1}{a-c} \frac{\left(G+\frac{ad-bc}{a-c}\right)^2+\frac{(a-c)(b-d)-2(ab-bc)}{a-c}G-\left(\frac{ad-bc}{a-c} \right)^2-bd}{G-\frac{ad-bc}{a-c}}
\end{equation}
This goes to the integration form as in the first answer.

Comment: You should edit your original post to include this, not create another post altogether.